# Self interruption of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The task is to make a free thread which will be interrupted when a definite period of time expires. My code doesn't work at all. At break points I have irrelevant threads. What can I try to resolve this?

```
public class HotThread implements Runnable {
       
    public HotThread() {
        this.file = null;        
    }
}


public class FreeThread extends HotThread {

    private final int timeout;
    Timer timer;
    InterruptByTimer task; 

    public FreeThread(int timeout) {
        super();
        this.timeout = timeout;
        timer = new Timer();
        task = new InterruptByTimer(timer);
        timer.schedule(task, timeout);
    }
    

    private class InterruptByTimer extends TimerTask {
        Timer timer;
        public InterruptByTimer(Timer timer){
            this.timer = timer;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run(){
            interruptThisThread(timer);
        }
    }
    
    public void interruptThisThread(Timer timer){
            timer.cancel();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}
```

Comment: HotThread class - where is run() ??

Comment: Do you mean signals? Like `SIGINT` and co? To interrupt a thread you must wake it, how can it be asleep and call something to interrupt threads? Signals on the other hand (I have no clue how they work in Java) involve the OS calling a pointer given to it earlier and when we return putting what we were doing before back in registers and whatnot.

Comment: @Batty, I just didn't show run. It is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) :

> A thread sends an interrupt by invoking interrupt on the Thread object for the thread to be interrupted. For the interrupt mechanism to work correctly, **the interrupted thread must support its own interruption.**

This support must be implemented in your thread run method (which I don't see in your code). There are several example in the tutorial. Something like this in the `run` method should do the trick :

```
while( continueWork) {
    doSomeWork();
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
        return;
    }
}
```

For interrupting your thread in your timerTask, you'll need to have a reference to it, which you can pass to the constructor :

```
public class FreeThread extends HotThread {

    private final int timeout;
    Timer timer;
    InterruptByTimer task; 

    public FreeThread(int timeout) {
        super();
        this.timeout = timeout;
        timer = new Timer();
        task = new InterruptByTimer(timer, Thread.currentThread());
        timer.schedule(task, timeout);
    }

     private class InterruptByTimer extends TimerTask {
        Timer timer;
        Thread thread;
        public InterruptByTimer(Timer timer, Thread thread){
            this.timer = timer;
            this.thread = thread;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){

            interruptThisThread(timer);
        }
    }

    public void interruptThisThread(Timer timer, Thread thread){
        timer.cancel();
        thread.interrupt();
    }

}
```

BTW, I don't understand why you pass the timer to your task, as the `cancel()` is called in `interruptThisThread` anyway.

Comment: Well, this is all very well. But frankly speaking the runnable interface confuses me. If it were an object, that would be more familiar for me. As it is an interface, I just can't find the necessary thread to invoke the interrupt() method. Could you help me here?

Comment: @graham is right, as you call interrupt from your timer you cannot directly use Thread.currentThread(). I'll edit my answer to make this part more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that [Timer class in Java creates a background thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).  So, when you call Thread.currentThread(), the actual thread it finds and interrupts is the timer thread itself, instead of the FreeThread.

To fix this - you should pass in the FreeThread as a constructor argument to InterruptByTimer.  Store it as a member in InterruptByTimer, then when the timer is triggered you can pass it as an argument to interruptThisThread (of course you will have to change that method to accept a thread argument).  Then inside interruptThisThread you can call interrupt on the thread object passed in.

Pierre Rust makes a valid point - the run method of your FreeThread will have to support interrupts, either by checking Thread.interrupted() or by catching InterruptedException.